# How i can determine: $\lim_{x\to1} \frac{x^{\frac{1}{3}}-1}{x^{\frac{1}{4}}-1}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

This is actually a limit tending to 1, if you can help me see how are the steps to multiply the factors, because it seems that there are many multiplications and this confuses me a lot!  $$\lim_{x\to1} \frac{x^{\frac{1}{3}}-1}{x^{\frac{1}{4}}-1}$$

Without L'Hôpital's rule and derivation.

Any hint or way about how to do it?

Comment: try substituting $x=y^{12}$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set $y=x^{1/12}$. Then $$\frac{x^{1/3}-1}{x^{1/4}-1}=\frac{y^{4}-1}{y^{3}-1}=
\frac{y^{3}+y^{2}+y+1}{y^{2}+y+1}.$$

$$\lim_{y\rightarrow 1}\frac{y^{3}+y^{2}+y+1}{y^{2}+y+1}=\frac{4}{3}.$$

Comment: @user73276 You are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Hints:

Try to prove and put the following together

$$x^{1/3}-1=\frac{x-1}{x^{2/3}+x^{1/3}+1}$$

$$x^{1/4}-1=\left(x^{1/2}\right)^{1/2}-1$$

$$x^{1/2}-1=\frac{x-1}{x^{1/2}+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

There is a formula :
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\dfrac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}=n\cdot a^{n-1}$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{x^\frac13-1}{x^\frac14-1}$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{x^\frac13-1^\frac13}{x-1}\times\dfrac{x-1}{x^\frac14-1^\frac14}$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{x^\frac13-1^\frac13}{x-1}\times\dfrac1{\dfrac{x^\frac14-1^\frac14}{x-1}}$$
$$\dfrac13\cdot 1^{\frac13-1}\times \dfrac{1}{\dfrac14\cdot 1^{\frac14-1}}$$
$$\dfrac43$$

Comment: Very thanks indeed!

Comment: It is my pleasure